# How to get the collection name from called API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm working on a node js application with mongoDB. Where I need help to get the collection name when I call the API for that collection.I want to use it in Middleware functions.

I got the method of that called API from this.

`const getmethod = req.method;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create `Middleware` and get and bind the collection list with the request as follows.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connection = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017');

const getmethod = req.method;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    connection.on('open', function () {
        connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, names) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                //Error in get collection
                req.collectionName = '';
                mongoose.connection.close();
                next();
            } else {
                console.log(names);
                if(names.includes(getmethod)){
                    req.collectionName = getmethod;
                }else{
                    //there is no collection exist for this method
                    req.collectionName = '';
                }
                mongoose.connection.close();
                next();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It will return the collections list from DB. But I need only that one collection Name each time for which I'm calling the api .For **Example**, I am calling the api to get customer in that case I want the name of that customer's collection Name.

Comment: @sohilpatel You can check your method exist in your DB, if yes then you can bind collection name otherwise blank, I edited my answer, maybe its help you